# FIFO Queue in Embedded C - Counters will overflow?

Tags: c, embedded, fifo, integer-overflow

so I'm reading a textbook on RTOS and there's a section that talks about FIFO queue's. I want to implement the code provided in the book for a UART device. I looked through the code and saw that the counters in the code don't reset. The counters are 32 bits, so they can go up to 2^32, but what if they were to be implemented in a device that goes past that value? **If the counters overflow, will they wrap around and continue working normally as counters?**

```
#include <stdint.h>

#define Size 32 //temporary value. It can be any value 2^n

uint32_t volatile TxPutI;//Counter 1
uint32_t volatile TxGetI;//Counter 2
static char TxFifo[size];
void TxFifo_Init(void)
{
    TxPutI = TxGetI = 0;
}
int TxFifo_Put(char data)
{
    if( (TxPutI - TxGetI)&~(Size-1) )
        return 0;
    TxFifo[TxPutI&(Size-1)] = data;
    TxPutI++; //it can overflow
    return 1;
}
int TxFifo_Get(char *datapt)
{
    if( TxPutI == TxGetI )
        return 0;
    *datapt = TxFifo[TxGetI & (Size-1)];
    TxGetI++; //it can overflow
    return 1;
}
uint16_t TxFifo_Size(void) //If someone can explain how this work, that'd be awesome!
{
    return( (uint16_t)(TxPutI - TxGetI) );
}
```

A special condition in the book is that the value Size must be 2^n. Does this condition keep the counters from causing an incorrect index? Thank you

Comment: did you make a note of if( (TxPutI - TxGetI)&~(Size-1) ) and  if( TxPutI == TxGetI ) ?

Comment: Yea, this code was written with a macro and those are supposed to return false ( return(FAIL), where FAIL is defined in the book as a 0 when the macro is implemented).

Comment: the posted code is missing the inclusion of the needed header files!  One result is the code does not compile.  Please edit the question to include the needed header files.  (we are not really interested in guessing as to which header files the actual code is including.)

Comment: regarding: `//If someone can explain how this work, that'd be awesome!
{
    return( (uint16_t)(TxPutI - TxGetI) );`  return a value that is the result of subtracting the end index of the used part of the queue - the index of the queue that is not yet consumed.

Comment: the posted code causes the compiler to output a long list of warning and error messages. If you want any significant help, then compile with the warnings enabled, then fix those warnings.

Comment: regarding: `char static TxFifo[size];`  1) in modern 'C', the modifier 'static' must be before the 'type'.  2) the variable `size` has not been declared

Comment: Thank you. I added the header file. I left the variable Size out of convinience. It can be replaced with any value 2^n.

Comment: regarding: `if( (TxPutI - TxGetI)&~(Size-1) )` and `*datapt = TxFifo[TxGetI & (Size-1)];` what are you expecting these statements to perform.  Amongst other things, they do not compile,

Comment: regarding: `size`,  use an `enum` statement or a `#define` statement to give that name (which by convention should be all caps) a easily modified value

Comment: From my understanding if( (TxPutI - TxGetI)&~(Size-1) ) is supposed to see if the difference between the pointers are equal to the size for the queue. If so, you cannot add more elements.

Comment: *datapt = TxFifo[TxGetI & (Size-1)]; is supposed to add the data pointed to by index TxGetI to a temporary variable. It extracts the data. For UART, it's used to place data in the UART Data Register.

Comment: I mean, why is the returned value type uint16_t? If the size happens to be something larger than (2^16)-1, wouldn't this break the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't matter if these counters overflow. The arithmetic "just works" due to the properties of unsigned arithmetic. When a difference is taken, the operation does a "borrow" from the unrepresented upper bits, and the low bits of the result are correct. Since the difference must be much smaller than the max value of the type `uint32_t` the upper bits of the difference are always zero.

Here's an example using `uint8_t` to avoid large numbers. We'll use `uint8_t` `getI` and `putI` variables, and a FIFO with size 16. `getI` and `putI` start out at 0. After 263 insertions and 254 removals, `getI` is 254 and `putI` is 7 (263 - 256 due to overflow). In unsigned arithmetic, 7 - 254 is 9. Work through some examples!

In the implementation given, the size of the FIFOs must also be a power of two because bitwise is used for modulo operations, and the cute trick for testing to see if the FIFO is full.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I understand how it works now! I'm just a little confused about the uint16_t type for the TxFifo_Size() function. This code seems to assume that the size will be 16 bits. Does this have something to do with the modulo operation as well?

Comment: @Pablo: No, the 16-bit choice appears rather arbitrary. The maximum is 32 of course given the definition of `Size` and so even `uint8_t` would be sufficient, I can only assume that 16-bit arithmetic happens to be efficient on this platform or that wiggle room for larger spaces was desired. The natural generic choice would be `size_t` though if squeezed for space/cycles `uint_fast8_t`, coupled with a static assertion on the value of Size, may be warranted.